# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string

I deployed my asp.net web application on somee.com, whenever I login into this site (ipc.somee.com) it gives me a network related error like:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296071
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308555
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +920
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +434
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5311099
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +558
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +67
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   Default.log(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\users\sreekanth\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\IPCWebApp\IPCWebApp\Default.aspx.cs:43
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +124
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Comment: The solution for me was in point 8 of the given answer. And add on top of that that I had the incorrect name for the Server in my application `ConnectionStrings` key value, which I had to change in the connection string. From: `"Default": "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TodoApp;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"` to `"Default": "Server=localhost;Database=TodoApp;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"`

Answer (score 67):

Sql Server fire this error when your application don't have enough rights to access the database. there are several reason about this error . To fix this error you should follow the following instruction.

1. Try to connect sql server from your server using management studio . if you use windows authentication to connect sql server then set your application pool identity to server administrator .
2. if you use sql server authentication then check you connection string in web.config of your web application and set user id and password of sql server which allows you to log in .
3. if your database in other server(access remote database) then first of enable remote access of sql server form sql server property from sql server management studio and enable TCP/IP form sql server configuration manager .
4. after doing all these stuff and you still can't access the database then check firewall of server form where you are trying to access the database and add one rule in firewall to enable port of sql server(by default sql server use 1433 , to check port of sql server you need to check sql server configuration manager network protocol TCP/IP port).
5. if your sql server is running on named instance then you need to write port number with sql server name for example 117.312.21.21/nameofsqlserver,1433.
6. If you are using cloud hosting like amazon aws or microsoft azure then server or instance will running behind cloud firewall so you need to enable 1433 port in cloud firewall if you have default instance or specific port for sql server for named instance.
7. If you are using amazon RDS or SQL azure then you need to enable port from security group of that instance.
8. If you are accessing sql server through sql server authentication mode them make sure you enabled "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode" sql server instance property.
   [image]
9. Restart your sql server instance after making any changes in property as some changes will require restart.

if you further face any difficulty then you need to provide more information about your web site and sql server .

Comment: I'm running into this issue, but I was able to connect once before and now I can't from asp.net. Connection string is good. I believe it has something to do with entity framework. Still investigating and not sure if that is the issue for above question.

Comment: Also, I'm connecting to a shared host on godaddy, if that helps any, from my local box which, like I said, I was able to do that before and no issue still with Management Studio.

Comment: Definitely a permission issue, at least for me. asp.net is trying to create its own db, which on godaddy with shared host you can only create db's through the UI.

Comment: You can't create database from asp.net application because userid and password that you use to connect to sql server don't have that permission to do that. if you want to create new database then you need to use godaddy web interface only.

Comment: I am also receiving this error except I am not trying to create any tables or new columns. It will work for a minute and then when I try changing something and save it I get this error for about an hour or so.

Comment: Although this was closed, the question and answer were very particular.  In particular #5 above (port number) in web.config helped immeasurably!

Comment: for Entity Framework in remote connection the step #5 is a solution

Comment: For me the issue was that the service wasn't started (even though it is set to automatic). I went to services, clicked start and problem solved.

Comment: Had this issue and needed to specify the different port I used at the ConnectionString using the **address,port**

Comment: in my case point 2 was the reason - "if you use sql server authentication then check you connection string in web.config of your web application and set user id and password of sql server which allows you to log in ."

Comment: In my case there was some weird stuff with config file, where connection string was stored. Worked after I replaced it with a file from installation.