# SQL Connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have developed a website using Visual Studio 2012's inbuilt template for asp.net website.

It worked fine with ASP.NET development server.

When I uploaded the website on IIS. I faced the error mentioned below when I tried to login.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details.

**STACK TRACE**

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6675286
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +688
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +6701832
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6703968
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6704427
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +610
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1049
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +74
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6706995
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2192
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1012
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6711619
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +152
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +229
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +134
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +3790907
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +10941050
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +91

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +10941121
   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMetadataWorkspace(String providerName, DbConnection connection, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +168
   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateEntityConnection(ConnectionStringSettings setting, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +298
   System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipEntities(ConnectionStringSettings setting) +51
   System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider.IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName) +180
   System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName) +794
   LoginPage.Login1_Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\TimeCard\LoginPage.aspx.cs:19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +160
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +93
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

My webconfig file is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TimeCard-20131218110938;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TimeCard-20131218110938.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeCardConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeCard;Integrated Security=SSPI"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MCASConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeCardConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeCard;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin" />
    </authorization>
    <compilation debug="true" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation >

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/"/>
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
          name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

What should be  the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256533/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne

Comment: The problem is very common, check the link in my answer and there are several steps to be done follow that and if you get error even after that please let me know..!!

Answer (score 3):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
> Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
> log for error details.

**There are two properties of LocalDB that cause problems when running under full IIS:**

> 1.LocalDB needs user profile to be loaded
>
> 2.LocalDB instance is owned by a single user and private (by default)

Most probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user.

Searched Google and found this great post:

[Using LocalDB with Full IIS, Part 1: User Profile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx)

I too had this problem when I deployed an ASP.NET MVC 4 app to a new Website in my local IIS and it created a new application pool.
As the post above describes one must enable setProfileEnvironment=true for the AppPool in the file

```
 C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config.
```

So add this

```
<add name="MyAppPoolName" />
<processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity"
              loadUserProfile="true"
              setProfileEnvironment="true" />
</add>
```

After changing the config code, don't forget to restart the app pool.

Now you should read this second post to deal with LocalDb Instance Ownership:

[Using LocalDB with Full IIS, Part 2: Instance Ownership](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` for your database in the connection strings - if this is a server it needs to be replaced with the name of the live server's DB instance.

Here's your config section

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TimeCard-20131218110938;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TimeCard-20131218110938.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeCardConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeCard;Integrated Security=SSPI"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MCASConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeCardConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeCard;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Your live database server doesn't know where `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` is. You will need to update these [connections strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) to point to the database your server is using.

I assume you'll need to update the credentials too.

Comment: Can you guide to any example as I am just beginner in software development

Comment: The thing is i cant even attach the mdf file to the management studio

Comment: @SPandya I've tried to expand, I'm not exactly sure what more I can add - can you contact your hosting provider's support team to ask about connections and deploying the database?

Comment: the database is in the App_Data folder of the solution

Comment: Which one? You have 4 dbs set up in your config file, at least one of them isn't connecting and we can't tell which without your code. Personally I don't mess with MDF files, I script the db and deploy it to live that way. The other poster has given excellent diagnostic steps, your hosting providers know the environment... we're going at this blind I'm afraid!

Comment: well the first one with the `connectionstring` name `DefaultConnection`is causing the problem. as If I directly run the page which is using the other three db its working perfect. The problem is with the first database only

Comment: i am simply hosting it on IIS server by copying the entire site  to wwwroot of inetpub directory. It not going live its intranet application only

Answer (score 0):

This one

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
```

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TimeCard-20131218110938;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TimeCard-20131218110938.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeCardConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeCard;Integrated Security=SSPI"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MCASConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="TimeCardConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TimeCard;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What I found is that the error is occurring because of the LocalDb database present in the App_Data folder

Comment: @SPandya Are you using `.mdf` file