# Creating a Service Based Database in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am having problems creating a Service Based Database on Visual Studio 2013 Community.

Basically, the problem is that when I attempt to add a Service Based Database to any of my projects I get an error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details)

In the past I have been able to add Databases to my projects without any issues. What has changed between now and then is that I started using SQL Server 2014 to work with a Java Project. I assume that installing SQL Server 2014 has changed some configuration settings that are now preventing me from creating a local database in Visual Studio.

I was able to resolve this by changing the name of the server (as configured in Visual Studio through Tools>Options>Database Tools>Data Connections) to SQLEXPRESS and was able to create a database, however, when I went to create a data source from the database, I got to the final step before I got the message:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified

After downloading some files and installing them I saw no effects. I really still want to use a local database, and after trying to return back to using a local database I can't get anything at all to work. Now, no matter what I try I get the error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occured while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   wa not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

If I want to work with local databases in Visual Studio, can I do this with SQL Server 2014 installed? If so, is there anywhere that I am going wrong?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I managed to fix my problem.

To create a local database I had to use the SQL Server Instance name **(localDB)\v11.0** and install **2012 LocalDB**. It would appear as though installing SQL Server 2014 updated the 2012 version of LocalDB to a 2014 version, which Visual Studio 2013 is not compatible with.

I would thank everyone for the help, but there is no-one to thank.

Comment: After googling for hours, this is what gave me the answer! I tried (local), (local)

Comment: Where did you download the 2012 version?

Answer (score 0):

**Try running Visual Studio 2013 as administrator**. It worked for me.

I found here ( [A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256533/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne) ) that the error is related with rights accessing databases.