# Catching SQL Connection Error and retrying

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, error-handling, webforms

I have a web application, it's working fine and doesn't really run into any issues. However, if the SQL Server is being restarted, or if it loses connection, then the application falls over with the standard error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I've got all of the initialisation within a `try / catch` block, however, it doesn't seem to stop this error, all I want to it do is catch the error, wait 10 seconds, and then try again - I've already got the retry code sorted; it just won't catch this error.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256533/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne

Comment: Are you closing the connection properly? Initialization inside try/catch might no be enough if the connection object goes beyond it. Also this issue suggests that you may have long living connections, and if so, please try to get rid of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you globally catch this in your `Application_Error` in the `Global.asax` file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var error = Server.GetLastError();
    //... do your handling here ...
}
```