# MySQL Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am trying to connect to the mysql database through a asp.net webservice but it gives me this error

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

I am using MySQL database and my connection string is

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=test;User Id=root;Password=;Integrated Security=True"
```

Almost all the solutions I have seen so far are for MS SQL. Thanks in advance

Comment: u sure mysql is running?

Comment: yea, i tried C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqladmin ping and produced this: mysqld is alive @Iceman

Comment: See here guy:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256533/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne

Answer (score 0):

Been a bit busy but today decided to sit and really work on it and here is how I solved it, I added a reference to MySQL Data for the project(After installing .net connector of course) then used MySql.Data.MySqlClient imports instead of System.Data.SqlClient and everything else e.g. instead of SqlConnection changed to MySqlConnection and voila, for the MySQL worked like a charm