# DB Connection Problem while using Microsoft Identity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, owin

Getting the following error "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server" , Using .NET 4.5. Deployed the Web application on my Local IIS 7.0 instance.

Trying to do a local setup of the application and trying to connect to the remote DB Server. The following is the code which used Microsoft Identity Framework to check the login credentials.

```
            var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
            var user = userManager.Find(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);
```

But I was able to connect to the remote DB using SQL Server Management Studio.

Little help would be highly useful. the following is the stack trace

```
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +353
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +118
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +268
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +128
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +485
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +560
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +18
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +230
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +914
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +117
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +211
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +128
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +156
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +124
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +292
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +187
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +75
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +482
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +177
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +272
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +69
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +66
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +209
   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +172
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +498
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +43
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<FindAsync>d__12.MoveNext() +353
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +348
   Website.Login.Login_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in C:\Work\www\web\mysite\Login.aspx.cs:38
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +188
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1964
```

Comment: what does the exception message say?

Comment: Failed to login with 'username'

Comment: Can you show us your connection string. Looks like you are not connecting to server with an SQL accout.

Comment: <connectionStrings> 
    <add name="DefaultSQLServer" connectionString="Server=remoteIPAdress;Database=MyDB;User ID=UserName;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: @DurgaPrasad can you use that same userName and login, open up Sql Mangement Studio and connect to the database?

Comment: Yes it's opening in SSMS and in visual studio db connection too. The problem is with framework configuration in the local. This application is running in production well. I was unable to do local setup to proceed with further enhancements to the application. Please help.

Comment: maybe you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256533/a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-conne

Comment: I resolved this problem by overriding the DefaultConnection String in my code. Thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overrided the DefaultConnection in my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

namespace MyWebsite
{
    public class MyApplicationDBContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public MyApplicationDBContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    }
    
    
}
```

Then changed the config file

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=serverip,portnumber;initial catalog=ICE;user id=uid;password=pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This happened because, defaultconnection is configured in .NET configuration file (machine.config) so the IIS is taking only this configuration file. By overriding this in the code is the best solution I got after very long search.