# SQL Server remote access via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

There are two physical servers. A managed Linux server (the server on which the application is hosted) and a Windows unmanaged server on which the database is located. I access the database with EF.

Access to the MS SQL Server database works locally on my computer, as well as on other computers that are in a different network than my home network. However, this only works with debug (localhost hosted).

The application is not hosted on the standard 443 port but on port 8080 for the time being.

I have already had the ports opened according to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/sql-server-ports/ba-p/384096%20this%20tutorial). Open ports TCP 1433, 4022, 1434, UDP 1434. All but 135 were opened. Port 135 could not be opened because quote of the server operator: "Only unprivileged ports are allowed (between 1024 and 65535)". However, I have not managed to find the reason for the failure.

Now I wanted to ask if there is a way to connect without this port being open, since port 1433 is supposedly necessary for connecting to an SQL instance.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16257101/11932313) as well.

Are there any other reasons why a connection cannot be established?

The error message:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could
> not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to
> SQL Server)

In addition I get this logging information:

> Entity Framework Core 6.0.3 initialized  using provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.3' with options: None

I have tried it with allowing the ip adress aswell. "Ja" stands for "Yes".

[image: I have tried it with allowing the ip adress aswell. Ja stands for Yes]

Comment: What happens when you try to telnet from your linux managed box into the remote windows box on port 1433 ?

Comment: @MauricioAtanache Using: `> telnet xxxxxxxx 1433`

Produce: `Trying xxxxxxx...`
`telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: But you mention you are able to connect to the remote box from other computers, so this has something to do with your linux box firewall configuration

Comment: Or maybe your remote server is only accepting connections from certain pre set IPs

Comment: Have you configured the outbound rule on your linux server ? something like iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d <your server ip> --dport 1433 -j ACCEPT

Comment: `But you mention you are able to connect to the remote box from other computers, so this has something to do with your linux box firewall configuration`
This is working with hosting the application on localhost on my machine... or other machines